# Wordpress error log - only displays decimal number

Tags: php, wordpress, error-log

I have a WordPress site I'm developing and my `php_errorlog` will register the following line every time a page loads -

> [30-Oct-2016 01:20:03 UTC] 0.85

I have no idea what 0.85 means? Anyone?